# Specific Regex/Regex Condition

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble grabbing a specific piece of text.

My input is:

```
PMT(B1+B144+B145*1/12.0,B148+B149*1*12.0,B1)
```

I want to grab all the `B1`'s, but when I'm trying to do that I'm getting `B1`, `B144`, `B148`, `B1`. My first solution was to check the following character. So I came up with the regex `B1[\W]`. There are two problems with this: One it ends up grabbing the non word character, and two it doesn't work with "=B1".

How can I grab specific `B1`s? For this example I want the first and last `B1`.

Edit: I'm using the Java String function replaceAll

Comment: My eyes hurt. Anyways, what language/flavor are you using ?

Comment: I'm using java String function replaceAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `B1(?!\\d)` which means:

- `B1` : match `B1`
- `(?!\\d)` : not followed by a digit

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use word boundaries:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("\\bB1\\b", "");
```